# Assign roles to users for serverless firebase app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, user-roles

I have a serverless application in React that uses a firebase firestore.

The app creates new users programmatically and data to a doc with name the same as the newly created user id.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        customerEmail.current.value, 
        customerPassword
    ).then(function(user) {
        console.log("UID!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", user, user.user.uid)
        firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('sessions')
        .doc(user.user.uid).set(
            {...context.state}
        ).then(() => {
            console.log("DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!")
        })
    })
```

Next I want to assign roles as I create these users.

I really want to use the admin sdk to assign custom claims to these users - is there a way to do this while remaining serverless?

If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You indeed need to use the Admin SDK for that.

As explained in the [dedicated section of the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk), “Custom claims should be set from a privileged server environment **by the Firebase Admin SDK**”.

With “privileged server environment” the doc means a server that you fully control or a **Cloud Function in your Firebase Project** that runs back-end code (and that you also control, since it is in your own Project).

[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) are "a **serverless** framework that lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features".

For example with the Admin Node.js SDK, you just have to call the [`setCustomUserClaims()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth.html#set-custom-user-claims) method, passing the `uid` of the user and an object defining the claims to be set.

In your case, you should most probably trigger a Cloud Function upon user creation, see the Cloud Functions corresponding [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation).

---

You don't give a lot of details on which kind of roles you want to assign. If there are different possible roles, you will need a way to decide which role(s) to assign to which user.

You may be interested by the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) I wrote on "How to create an Admin module for managing users access and roles"

Comment: So do I need to create a web server? The admin sdk does not seem to work with React? I get Can't resolve 'http2'

Comment: No, you don't need to create a web or an application server. As said above, all of that can be done through [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), "a **serverless** framework that lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features"